# Adding rows to a UITable from an array

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, uitableview, cells

I have a UITable, and class who is it's datasource and delegate. The class has a property called `logItemsArray` which contains a number of objects which are used as data for a row (customer name, date added etc...) (the cells have a special class to which I pass these objects and it returns a cell).

I also have a method called `loadNextLogEvents` which loads some data from a web server and adds items into the `logItemsAraay` (it automatically loads the data for the next 100 rows).

This method is called once from the `viewWillApear` method and also from a button to load the next events.

The table view's dataSource `numberOfRowsInTable` returns the count of the `logItemsArray`.

The thing is: How do I "update" the table from the `loadNextLogEvents` to use the new data to load cells (the array is updated so both the `numberOfRowsInTable` and the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method will return the desired result of new row, I just need to trigger them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```